# How to map multiple objects properties in table respectively from state in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

State:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        id: [],name:[]
```

Fetch:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('some_api')
        .then(res => {
            let x = res.data.results.map(obj => obj.id);
            let y = res.data.results.map(obj => obj.full_name);
            this.setState({id: x});
            this.setState({name: y});
})
}
```

Render:

```
{this.state(i need to map both id and name here).map((item=>{
                        return(
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style={{textAlign:'center'}}><Checkbox/></td>
                                <td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{item.id}</td>
                                <td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{item.full_name}</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>)
                }))}
```

I am able to fetch values from one object property, but not all.
Data is in this format :

```
"results": [
{
  "id": 25,
  "full_name": "William Lane",
  "email": "staff_24@trash-mail.com",
  "username": "staff_24"
},
{
  "id": 26,
  "full_name": "Christine Thompson",
  "email": "staff_25@trash-mail.com",
  "username": "staff_25"
}
```

And I have to return it into table form as in the above code.

Comment: initial value of `tableData` should be any array: `tableData: []`

Comment: I already did that. but  it only map a single data value. I need multiple datas to map.

Comment: Do you mean by `map(obj => ({id: obj.id, full_name: obj.full_name}))`

Comment: I have updated the code, Please have a look now.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example to get all your github repos:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox'

class MyGitHubRepos extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const user = '<YOUR_USER>'
    axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}/repos`)
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data
        this.setState({ data })
    })
  }

  cell = content =>
    <td style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
      {content}
    </td>

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.data.map(item=> (
            <tr key={item.id}>
              {this.cell(<Checkbox/>)}
              {this.cell(item.id)}
              {this.cell(item.name)}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}

export default MyGitHubRepos
```

Check out the way you obtain data (the shape of `res` in `componentDidMount`). Your data should save in an array (no two arrays with ids and names), this is 
a little unintelligible. And, if you want, create a function to render a cell to avoid repeat code.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
  class Test extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tableData:[]
        };
      }


      componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('some_api')
          .then(res => {
             this.setState({
               tableData: res.data.results
             })
          })
      }

      render() {
       <div>
        <table>
         <tbody>
         {this.state.tableData.map((item,i)=>
          <tr id={i}>
            <td style={{textAlign:'center'}}><Checkbox/></td>
            <td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{item.id}</td>
            <td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{item.full_name}</td>
          </tr>
         )}
         </tbody>
        <table>
       </div>
      }

    }
```